# Change border color on angular-archwizard steps

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I'm using angular-archwizard to create circle steps to navigate. When I click on different steps I can view the right circle step border colored(in my case orange) until I click on the last step. When I click on the last step also the other steps change border color and become green.
I inspected the elements and I saw that it's applied a css on this

```
aw-wizard-navigation-bar.horizontal.large-empty ul.steps-indicator li.done 
.step-indicator
```

and the 'li.done' it's applied on every steps(with the green border-color).

I would to know if there is a way to do for dont't apply the last 'li.done' when I click on the last step. Or if there another way to work right.

```
<aw-wizard  *ngIf="items.length > 0" navBarLayout="large-empty" 
  style="padding-bottom: 0.5rem" style="width: 100%" 
     navigationMode="free">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <aw-wizard-step [stepId]="i" [navigationSymbol]="{  symbol: 
       '&#xf298;', fontFamily: 'FontAwesome'}"
      stepTitle="{{item.statoContattoDescrizione}}" 
    (stepEnter)="passToStep($event,i)">
    </aw-wizard-step> ...
</aw-wizard>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css. Add something like this to your stylesheet

```
ul.steps-indicator li:last-child .done .step-indicator{ 
         border-color:orange;
}
```

or sass

```
ul.steps-indicator{
    li:last-child { 
        .done{
         .step-indicator{
           border-color: orange;
         }
        }   
    }
}
```

that would remove the green border for example.

Comment: mmh.. the problem is that however when I click on the last step it add the property li.done to all the other steps(and this means border color green to all steps)

Comment: If you don’t want the effect at all it’s easier. .done{border:none}

Comment: Only .done{border: none} or ul.steps-indicator .done{border:none}?

Comment: Yes your rule is more specific. Its better

Comment: mmh doesn't work. it seems when I click on the last step the property .done is applied on the all steps and there is no way to change the css. (I think is the component aw-wizard step behaviour).

Comment: No its just a matter of css selector priority. Check your f12, inspect element in html and you will see which css rule that makes the border green. Paste it here so I can have a look at it

Comment: `aw-wizard-navigation-bar.horizontal.large-empty ul.steps-indicator li.done .step-indicator {
    border: 2px solid #393;
}`

Comment: I want that when click on the last step and back in other step the clicked step show orange border color and the other not click show green border color

Comment: Just for start add that complete selector in your css and change border: none. Mayby we can make i smaller if we first makes it hit

Comment: `/deep/ aw-wizard-navigation-bar.horizontal.large-empty ul.steps-indicator li.done .step-indicator { 
  border: none !important; 
}`

Comment: i dont see any border of steps when I click on the last step

Comment: Perfekt now you have selector that targets the element. Let me think about the info you just wrote, about the orange

Comment: ok now I want that when I riclick on another step, the selected border color show orange color

Comment: while the other step remain the same(e.g green or other color

Comment: Im not able to check it, but something like that. I update the answer. If you cant solve it I'll add a snipplet

Comment: no, when I click on the last step it remains with the border:none

Comment: well if you look at my updated answer there is not any border:none. So you either added it somewhere or you have caching in the browser. You kan remove it in f12.

Comment: I mantain the border:none in my stylesheet.. Do I ha e ti remove it?

Comment: I remove the border:none from my stylesheet. I inspect the element and `aw-wizard-navigation-bar.horizontal.large-empty ul.steps-indicator li.done .step-indicator {
    border: 2px solid #393;
}`

Comment: Yes I updated the answer. But I cant help you fully. I only showed how you can target stuff with css. Im thinking about your description i detail obove. You said that when you click last step (.done class is added on every steps-indicator), but then you said that you wanted a class on the clicked steps and another for the ones that have not been clicked. You need to look if there is somekind of class that gets added when an step has been clicked. If not you need to look at the material component in detal

Comment: `/deep/ ul.steps-indicator li.done.navigable .step-indicator {
  color: #FF6C00 !important;
  border: 2px solid #FF6C00 !important;
  font-size: 24px;
}`

Comment: I find this solution.. the key is the .navigable class.! However thank u for the suggests